# JS Loop thru all different child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get dates from my table:

```
<th>Dates:</th>
<td>
   <a href="/dates">
      <span> 22 February 2019 </span> (UK)
      <span> 19 February 2019 </span> (DE)
   </a>
</td>
```

Preferred output:

```
dates {
 date1: '22 February 2019',
 country1: 'UK',
 date2: '19 February 2019',
 country2: 'DE'
}
```

EDIT: countries aren't must have, they are the second objective, I mostly care about dates.

Acceptable output:

```
dates {
 date1: '22 February 2019',
 date2: '19 February 2019'
}
```

I was trying loop each child element to get that output by treating each child to determinate what kind of type it is:

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn-getdates", function() {
  var dates = $(document).find('tr th:contains("Dates")').next('td');
  $(dates).children().each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
  });
});
```

But I get this output:

> 22 February 2019  (UK)  19 February 2019  (DE)

How could I store dates in an object??

Comment: The syntax of the  output you say you want is an object, not an array. You also don't have any *actual* dates here, just strings. Lastly, you'll have a much easier time if you wrap the countries in `span` elements as well.

Comment: You are right, I updated the question to fix it. Unfortunately, I can't change page design so countries must stay outside. On the other hand, I mostly care about dates will update the question to point it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See comments inline:

```js
// Get the anchor
let anchor = document.querySelector("[href='/dates']");

let result = {};

// Get the two spans
let span1 = anchor.querySelector("span");
let span2 = anchor.querySelector("span:nth-child(2)");

// Extract the first date and country
result.date1 = span1.textContent.trim();
result.country1 = span1.nextSibling.nodeValue.trim();  // <-- This is a text node

// Then the second:
result.date2 = span2.textContent.trim();
result.country2 = span2.nextSibling.nodeValue.trim();  // <-- This is a text node

console.log(result);
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<th>Dates:</th>
<td>
   <a href="/dates">
      <span> 22 February 2019 </span> (UK)
      <span> 19 February 2019 </span> (DE)
   </a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```